# Splitting Stock Price data for SVM classification

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, svm

I'm trying to use SVM to predict whether the price of a security will go up in the next 7 days using a prediction of the last 14 days of data. So far, I have extracted a dataset with 15 features and around 3000 samples (dates). However, I'm a little confused on how I should split my data for the x training set and y training set (and also for the testing sets for that matter).

Would this kind of split make sense in training?

x training set: (Pseudo code)

```
[Features from days 1-14 , Features from days 22-35, ......]
```

y training set: (Pseudo code)

```
[1 if price(day 21) > price(day 14) else -1 ,1 if price(day 42) > price(day 35) else -1, ....]
```

However, I feel like I'm losing alot of data due to the nature of the y-training set. Are there any better ways to model this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure I have fully understood how you have prepared the dataset, but anyway this what I think you could do.

- Take your 3000 samples with your 15 features, and add a new feature with meaning `the price went up in the last 7 days`. This new feature will be simply your `y`
- As for your test and training set, you could just order your samples by date, take the `X%` older as your training set, and the remaining as test set

You have a kind of toy example in [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/index.html) performing a similar kind of setup (section 4.6.1 *The Stock Market Data* includes a lab in R).